# My JavaScript functions/if-statements only works when placed in a certain order

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, function, if-statement

I'm making a basic site to create artists and upload songs to the artists to learn mysql, php, js.

I'm having trouble with the JavaScript that checks if you've entered a name for the artist and selected a picture. Or if the user is updating an existing artist. (I have PHP-code that works when JS fails).

Here's the JS-code:

```
function checkFormDetails(form, formEdit) {

    //set filename to lowercase
    var fileName = form.filePictureFileName.value.toLowerCase();

    //Check if user is updating a song
    if (form.txtArtist.value == formEdit.hidArtist.value && fileName == "") {
        return true;
    }

    //Checks if Artist-field is empty
    else if (form.txtArtist.value == "") {
        window.alert("Please enter a Artistname!");
        form.txtArtist.focus();
        return false;
    }

    //Checks if a picture is choosen
    else if (fileName == "") {
        window.alert("Please choose a Picture!");
        form.filePictureFileName.focus();
        return false;
    }


    //Checks if the file extension is correct
    else if (fileName.lastIndexOf(".jpg") == -1) {
        window.alert("Only '.jpg' files are allowed.");
        return false;
    } else
        return true;
}


//Copys the artist data from the hidden fields
function copyEditArtistFormData(formDel, formUpd) {
    formUpd.txtArtist.value = formDel.hidArtist.value;
    formUpd.hidId.value = formDel.hidId.value;
    formUpd.hidPictureFileName.value = formDel.hidPictureFileName.value;
}

//Confirmation for deleting a Artist
function verifyDeleteOfArtist(formDel) {
    var x = window.confirm('Do you want to delete the artist?');
    if (x) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}


//Resets the fiels to default
function resetNewUpdateArtistFormData(form) {
    form.txtArtist.value = "";
    form.filePictureFileName.value = null;
    form.hidId.value = "";
    form.hidPictureFileName.value = "";
}
```

In it's current state the edit-functions works. But I won't get a window.alert if I want to create a new artist and don't enter a name and/or choose a picture to upload.

If I move the if-statement that checks if the user is updating an artist to the end of the function. I get the window.alerts when failing to enter an artist name or picture. But when I want to edit an existing artist, the artistname is moved to the form, but the picture-file is not moved to the form, so I get an error telling me to choose a file.

Here's the two php-functions for saving and editing an artist:

```
function printRecord() {
    echo("<fieldset><legend>New/Edit Artist</legend>\n<form action=\"adminArtist.php\" method=\"post\"
        name = \"frmNewUpdateArtist\" enctype=\"multipart/form-data\" onsubmit=\"return checkFormDetails(this, frmEditDeleteArtist);\">\n");
    echo("<input type=\"hidden\" id=\"hidId\" name=\"hidId\" />\n");
    echo("<input type=\"hidden\" id=\"hidPictureFileName\" name=\"hidPictureFileName\" />\n");
    echo("<label>Artist<br /><input type=\"text\" id=\"txtArtist\" name=\"txtArtist\" autofocus=\"autofocus\"
        title = \"Artist\"/></label><br />\n");
    echo("<label>Picture<br /><input type=\"file\" id=\"filePictureFileName\" name=\"filePictureFileName\"
        title = \"Picture\" /></label><br />\n");
    echo("<input type=\"submit\" id=\"btnSave\" name=\"btnSave\" value=\"Save\" />\n");
    echo("<input type=\"button\" id=\"btnReset\" name=\"btnReset\" value=\"Reset\"
        onclick = \"resetNewUpdateArtistFormData(this.form);\"/>\n");
    echo("</form>\n</fieldset>\n");
}

function listArtists($dbConnection) {
    $strSQL = "SELECT * FROM tblartist";
    $recordSet = myDBQuery($dbConnection, $strSQL);
    echo("<fieldset>\n<legend>Stored Artists</legend>\n");
    while ($record = mysqli_fetch_assoc($recordSet)) {
        echo("<form action=\"adminArtist.php\" method=\"post\" name=\"frmEditDeleteArtist\" onsubmit=\"return verifyDeleteOfArtist(this);\">\n");
        echo("id: ".$record["id"].
            "<br />\n");
        echo("name: ".$record["name"].
            "<br />\n");
        echo("picture: ".$record["picture"].
            "<br />\n");
        echo("changedate: ".$record["changedate"].
            "<br />\n");
        $filePathAndName = "upload_jpg/".$record["picture"];

        echo("<img src=\"".$filePathAndName.
            "\" alt=\"".$record["picture"].
            "\" class=\"imgAnimation\" /><br />\n");
        echo("<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"hidId\" value=\"".$record["id"].
            "\" />\n");
        echo("<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"hidArtist\" value=\"".$record["name"].
            "\" />\n");
        echo("<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"hidPictureFileName\" value=\"".$record["picture"].
            "\" />\n");
        echo("<input type=\"button\" name=\"btnEdit\" value=\"Edit\" onclick=\"copyEditArtistFormData(this.form, frmNewUpdateArtist);\"/>\n");
        echo("<input type=\"submit\" name=\"btnDelete\" value=\"Delete\" />\n");
        echo("</form>\n\n");
    }
    echo("</fieldset>\n");

    myDBFreeResult($recordSet);
}
```

I guess this is a very basic problem, but I can't for the love of god figure out the problem. I'm also sorry if my code looks awful to you more experienced coders.

I'm thankful for any ideas on how to fix this.

Comment: work through your script using console.log() and validate the if/else conditions.

Comment: Log everything in your code and the values. It might be that you're not even retrieving them properly. From your code, for example, it might be that you're trying to get a value from a hidden or missing field.

Answer (score 0):

The 'else' statement should not go in all 'if's. You don't want only check if the artist is empty, or the file extension is wrong, you want to check All of them, so just use:

```
function checkFormDetails(form, formEdit){

  var result = true;
  //set filename to lowercase
  var fileName = form.filePictureFileName.value.toLowerCase();

        //Check if user is updating a song
  if (form.txtArtist.value != formEdit.hidArtist.value || fileName != "")
  {
      result = false;
  }

  //Checks if Artist-field is empty
  if(form.txtArtist.value == "")
  {
      window.alert("Please enter a Artistname!");
      form.txtArtist.focus();
      result = false;
  }

  //Checks if a picture is choosen
  if(fileName == "")
  {
        window.alert("Please choose a Picture!");
        form.filePictureFileName.focus();
        result = false;
  }

  //Checks if the file extension is correct
  if(fileName.lastIndexOf(".jpg") == -1)
  {
         window.alert("Only '.jpg' files are allowed.");
         result = false;
  }



  return result;





}
```